# How to display only date from datetime field in modelAdmin in Django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a model which has a column `created_at` which is actually a `datetime` field of this format `16.07.2019 12:26:37`.

I want to display only **date** present in this `created_at` field in **admin panel** in **Django**.

I can display the whole field's value which is **`datetime`** if I mention the `'created_at'` in `list_display` while creating modelAdmin.

How can I display only the **`date`** value in results page like this `16.07.2019`?

Are there any inbuilt filters to do that while registering the modelAdmin?

```
Python: 3.7.3
Django: 2.1.5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a method to the `ModelAdmin` class.

```
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_date_formatted',)

    def get_date_formatted(self, obj):
        if obj:
            return obj.date.date()
    get_date_formatted.admin_order_field = 'date'
    get_date_formatted.short_description = 'date'
```

Comment: I figured it out a few moments ago.
Thanks, BTW. It worked.

Comment: What If I have two date fields ?

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury you would need two methods, for example `get_date_start_formatted` and `get_date_end_formatted`. The line `return obj.date.date()` stripped down is `<model_instance>.<model_field>.<method>()` so you would need to make sure the model field being retrieved from the object is referring to the desired field on your model.